# How to structure returned data from an api in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, constants, axios

I'm using a React Native react-native-snap-carousel which simply displays a carousel with image, title and subtitle. The data is loaded via a static file:

```
export const ENTRIES2 = [
  {
      title: 'Favourites landscapes 1',
      subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
      illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/SsJmZ9jl.jpg'
  },
  {
      title: 'Favourites landscapes 2',
      subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
      illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/5tj6S7Ol.jpg'
  }
]
```

I have setup axios to retrieve data from an api:

```
axios.get('http://192.168.1.1/test')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);
        this.isLoading = false;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
```

how can I use this returned data to create a const structured in a similar way to the static file?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "const structured"? Do you mean state?

Comment: What is the shape of the data that is returned by the API? What is the output of the response?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy! You can set up your object however you need to like so. I'm assuming response.data is an array of entries here, but you'll have to modify to whatever your response uses.

```
axios.get('http://192.168.1.1/test')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data);
    let data = []
    response.data.forEach(entry => {
      data.push({
        title: entry.title,
        subtitle: entry.subtitle
      })
    })
    this.isLoading = false
  })
```

If this method is in your component (like in `componentDidMount`), you can use `setState` to add the data to your state and then use it in your component.

```
...
  subtitle: entry.subtitle
})
this.isLoading = false
this.setState({data})
```

Then in your render method:

```
render () {
  const {data} = state
  return(
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
    />
  )
}
```

The key here is creating the array of elements based off of what your api call returns, then saving those into the state of the component, which you can access to render them.

Comment: When building a new array from an existing array, use `map()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking the react-native-snap-carousel documentation, you can see the prop "data" is a array, look below.

```
return (
     <Carousel
          ref={(c) => { this._carousel = c; }}
          data={this.state.entries} <-- it's a array
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          sliderWidth={sliderWidth}
          itemWidth={itemWidth}
         />
 );
```

So, in your component create a state will be receive the data from api.

```
state = {
    data: []
}
```

And use axios to retrieve the data in the componentWillMount.

```
componentWillMount() {
   axios.get('http://192.168.1.1/test')
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data);

        this.setState({
            data: response.data
        }) 

        this.isLoading = false;
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.error = error
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
}
```